# Why is $a x+b y +c z= d$ a plane and not a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Say for example, i have the bojective function $6x^2 + 12y^2 = z$
shown by the green graph, and i want to minimize the objective function suject to the constraint function $x+y=0.5$ shown by the blue graph

Why does it show that the constraint function(blue) can take on any value of $z$?
Shouldn't the blue graph essentially just be a single line with $z=0.5$?

[image]

[image]

Comment: $x+y=0.5$ is a plane in 3 dimensions. What blue graph?

Comment: Why is it a plane instead of a line which sits at z=0.5. The blue graph in the images, ive uplaod a second image

Comment: It is unclear *why* you expect that $x+y=0.5$ would correspond to a line in the plane $z=0.5$. Both these equations correspond to planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: If you select values of x and y which add to the value 0.5. If you had a plane, it would show that the selected x and y values satisfy all values of z when z=0.5

Comment: @Joce How would you represent a single line equation?

Comment: $x+y=0.5$ is a line in 2D but in 3D it is a relationship between $x$ and $y$ and z is free to take any value. This makes it a vertical plane. If you look straight down from above this plane will intersect the $x, y$ plane in the line $x+y=0.5$

Comment: A single line in 3D is the interesection of *two* planes, so something like $\{ ax+by+cz = d \text{ and } a'x+b'y+c'z = d' \}$.
In arbitrary dimensions $\mathbb{R}^d$, a single equation $\sum_i=1^d a_i x_i = a_0$ denotes what is called a hyperplane, that is a space of dimension $R^{d-1}$.

Comment: Else a line can be parameterized, e.g. $(x,y,z) = (f_x(t),f_y(t),f_z(t)) = (a_x t +b_x, a_y t + b_y, a_z t + b_z)$.

Comment: The way that graphing an equation works is that you plot all points $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy the equation. If you plot all possible points $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy $6x^2 + 12y^2 = z$ you get the green surface. If you plot all possible points $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy $x + y = .5$ you get a plane. Just try plotting them all, you'll see.

Comment: Read the equation as $1\cdot x+1\cdot y+0\cdot z=0.5$. There is no reason to impose $z=0.5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

You can find the minimum, over the blue intersection curve (parabola)

[image]

Comment: And how would you expect to find the parabola?

Comment: $6(0.5-y)^2+12y^2= z$  when projected on the $Y\times Z$ plane.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I gather that it is the correspondence of equations and geometric lines and surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is the problem for you.

Indeed, when working in $\mathbb{R}^2$, there is no distinction between a line (that is, a subset that forms a space of dimension 1) and a *hyperplane*, which is an (affine) subspace of dimension $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$, that is, of dimension $1$ if the space is $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($d=2$).

So, let's explain that out.

If you have a space of dimension $d$ (picture it for $d=2$ and $3$, but this is valid in higher dimensions), an equation
$$
\sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i = a_0
$$
allows you to deduce **one** of the coordinates $x_i$ from the knowledge of all the others. This implies that this equation denotes a subspace whose dimension is just 1 less than the one of the original space: so one equation such as this gives a subspace of dimension $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$: a line if $d=2$, a plane if $d=3$.

Examples: in 2D, if you set $x_1=x^*_1$ and have $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 = a_0$, then you can deduce what $x_2$ is (unless $a_2  = 0$, then it is a plane parallel to the second axis).

In 3D, if you set $x_1=x_1^*$ (and if $a_1\not=0$) and have $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3 = a_0$, then you can deduce only a relationship $a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3 = (a_0-a_1 x_1^*)$ where the brackets are a constant. You see that you can have many such $x_2$ and $x_3$: in the plane where $x_1$ is the constant $x^*_1$ that you have chosen, $a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3 = (a_0-a_1 x_1^*)$ denotes a line. All these lines for different $x_1^*$ values form a plane, called an affine hyperplane.

In your figure, $x+y=0.5$ so $a_1=1$, $a_2=1$ and $a_3=0$ is the blue plane you have represented, and those lines are vertical lines $\{ y = 0.5-x^* \text{ and } x=x^*\}$ for different choices of $x^*$.